# Mongoose query stream closed before finishing streaming data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I used a stream to get all the data in a mongoDB collection machines:

```
module.exports.machineStream = () => models.machines.find().lean().cursor();
```

And then I process those data and write to another collection:

```
let writeCount = 0;

async function updateHistory(doc) {
  ...
  writeCount++;
  console.log(`writeCount: ${writeCount}`);
  await mongo.updateTrackerRecord();
}

async function processStream() {
  let readCount = 0;
  console.log(`${(new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Toronto' })).toString()}: price-tracker: start updating price tracker`);
  const stream = mongo.machineStream();
  stream.on('data', async (doc) => {
    readCount++;
    console.log(`readCount: ${readCount}`);
    stream.pause();
    await updateHistory(doc);
    stream.resume();
  }).on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    sentry.captureException(err);
  }).on('close', () => {
    console.log(`${(new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Toronto' })).toString()}: price-tracker: 1 end updating price tracker`);
  });
}
```

The following output shows that the stream close message is received before finishing reading the stream(total number of data is 4746):

```
readCount: 4726
writeCount: 4726
readCount: 4727
writeCount: 4727
readCount: 4728
writeCount: 4728
readCount: 4729
writeCount: 4729
readCount: 4730
writeCount: 4730
readCount: 4731
6/22/2020, 4:42:59 PM: price-tracker: 1 end updating price tracker
writeCount: 4731
readCount: 4732
writeCount: 4732
readCount: 4733
writeCount: 4733
readCount: 4734
writeCount: 4734
readCount: 4735
writeCount: 4735
readCount: 4736
writeCount: 4736
readCount: 4737
writeCount: 4737
readCount: 4738
writeCount: 4738
readCount: 4739
writeCount: 4739
readCount: 4740
writeCount: 4740
readCount: 4741
writeCount: 4741
readCount: 4742
writeCount: 4742
readCount: 4743
writeCount: 4743
readCount: 4744
writeCount: 4744
readCount: 4745
writeCount: 4745
readCount: 4746
writeCount: 4746
```

My question is:

1. why does this happen?
2. I want to close the mongoDB connection after all the read/write operations finish, how can I do it?

Comment: I don't think this should happen. Verify that the events are emitted in the order you claim and it's not just your logging that is out of order, then reduce the example to a single file and if it still reproduces with the most recent driver release consider reporting it as a bug.

Comment: @D.SM Thank you for the reply. I found that if I remove the "stream.pause()" and "stream.resume()" pair, then the problem cannot be reproduced. Maybe it is related to the asynchronous behaviour of  updateHistory();

Comment: Node streams are beyond my paygrade, can't help you there.